# JavaScript - Creating Label with same properties multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript to create a Label object. This Label object should be created when an event occurs. All is working fine. But, when the same event is triggered again, this is where I am seeing a problem: `"adding element with duplicate id"`. I have tried to destroy/delete the Label object and create it every time the event is triggered. But No Luck. Any Suggestions??

Please suggest, how to re-create the Label object with same properties again and again?

Please find the code

```
switch(locDetail)
        {
            case 'K1':
                klocation = "INDIA";
                //var oLocLabel1 = null;
                //alert("INDIA");
                //document.getElementById('LocLabelContent').innerHTML = "";
                var oLocLabel1 = new sap.ui.commons.Label("LocationDetailsLabel1");
                oLocLabel1.setText(klocation);
                oLocLabel1.placeAt("LocLabelContent1");
                //delete oLocLabel1;
                //document.getElementById('LocLabelContent').innerHTML = klocation;
                oLocLabel1.destroy();
                break;
```

If we create a object with new properties (appending a counter). Will that not cause extra objects?

Comment: "*I am using JavaScript to create a Label Object.*" Can you show us how?

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what the problem is, because I don't know anything about your code, because you didn't post it.

Comment: how are you deleting the object? $( "#label_1" ).remove();? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're creating a label *element*, if so you can create the label with all the properties and just clone it every time you need a new one, and set the ID with an increasing counter to get unique ID's, something like :

```
var label   = document.createElement('label'),
    counter = 0;

label.innerHTML = 'some label text';
label.style.color = 'red';

someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var lbl = label.cloneNode(true);
    lbl.id  = 'label_' + (++counter);

    document.body.appendChild(lbl);

}, false);
```